# State of modifier key resets upon pressing another key using GetKeyState and Keyboard.KeyIsDown

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, key, modifier

This problem has me stomped.

If I hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key and press any key, the program successfully records it in the WPF Window.KeyUp event and does as expected:

```
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.S && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        ButtonSave_Click(sender, null);
    }
}
```

Then things get interesting. This only works for the "first time" the event is fired. If I keep holding down Left Ctrl and press <kbd>S</kbd> again, the event fires byt the state of the <kbd>LeftCtrl</kbd> is up (not down).

So the ButtonSave_Click only fires ONCE if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down and key <kbd>S</kbd> is pressed many times. I have to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press it down again for it to detect it's state as being down.

At first I thought it was just a C# fluke but I'm seeing same thing when using C/C++ GetKeyState from user32.dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);
```

Replacing the above code with the following:

```
if (e.Key == Key.S && BitConverter.GetBytes(GetKeyState(0xA2))[1] > 0)
{
    ButtonSave_Click(sender, null);
}
```

And I get the same behavior, ButtonSave_Click only fires once no matter how many times I press <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down.

How can I work around this problem and what is going on?